# PGadmin crash if I drop a table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I'm trying to drop a table from the PGadmin3 GUI, which means right click and then `DROP TABLE`. In few seconds PGadmin crash.
Similar happen if I use `psql` adopting the shell; here I write:

`myDBname=> DROP TABLE my_table`

and it returns,

`myDBname->`

(note the difference between `=>` and `->`)

It seems that nothing is happen. But if I write `\dt` the table is still there. 
Anyone can help me?

Comment: add semicolon and it will drop it `myDBname=> DROP TABLE my_table;`, changed `->` in your case means it is contunuing the command in another line

Comment: ok, thanks for this tip ;)

Comment: But still I have the original problem....

Comment: please update your question. Clearly defining symptoms, quote logs if possible etc

Comment: I'm trying to drop a table from linux using the GUI of PGadmin3, which means right click on the desidered table and then DROP TABLE. Immediately PGadmin crash (it appears the common hourglass, and I can also wait more then 1 hour, but nothing happend). So I have to kill pgadmin's process in order to restart to work.